# Sending Voicebase transcription to database

Tags: python, sql, json, callback, twilio

I have set up a Twilio/Python app that makes calls, records those calls on a dual-channel, and sends them to Voicebase to be transcribed. Does anyone know how I can get a JSON response from the Voicebase API, and store that in a database? (Such as SQL or PostGreSQL.) I'm still having trouble getting the transcriptions in a way that doesn't involve using CURL in my terminal for each individual recording, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hello from VoiceBase support, and here are some example responses for the functionality you are requesting:

Getting a JSON response from the VoiceBase API

Here is some sample code using the requests library to submit a GET request for the specified $MEDIAID using your Bearer Token ($TOKEN)

```
import requests
import json

url = "https://apis.voicebase.com/v2-beta/media/$MEDIAID"

payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"transcript\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"
headers = {
    'content-type': "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
    'authorization': "Bearer $TOKEN",
    'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

response = requests.request("GET", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Parsing the transcript:

This sample code uses the JSON library to load the key/value pairs into a dictionary for parsing

```
transcript = json.loads(response.text)
job_status = transcript['media']['status']
```

Saving to Database

This code will use MySQLdb to open a connection to the database and save the value (in this case job_status)

```
import MySQLdb

db = MySQLdb.connect("localhost","user","password","database")
cursor = db.cursor()

query = "INSERT INTO table VALUES (%s)"

cursor.execute(query, (job_status))

db.commit()
db.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

In future I would recommend you post your code along with your question. It's much easier for everyone and people are much more likely to try and help you if they can see you have already had a go yourself.

If your python app is already submitting the recordings for transcription then instead of polling for the result for each individual recordings you can specify a callback URL on your server which VoiceBase will submit the transcription data to once each transcription is done. According to their docs you can request the response data as JSON when you submit your audio.

I've always used PHP so I've no experience with python web frameworks, but some basic server side code (using Django maybe?) running at the callback URL can probably process the VoiceBase data and save it to a database or whatever. In PHP this is the sort of thing you could achieve using a handful of lines of code.

It's probably worth looking at the guide VoiceBase provide for Twilio integration as they have a few examples which seem relevant. You can find it [here](https://www.voicebase.com/twilio-integration/).